# Python Split multiple values in a cell into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

What i'm trying to get is divide multiple values of cells into multiple rows and then get only the row who has the larger number value in fruit_weight column.

I've the following format:

```
fruit_type;fruit_color;fruit_weight
Apple|Banana;Red|Yellow;2|1
Orange;Orange;4
Pineapple|Grape|Watermelon;Brown|Purple|Green;12|1|15
```

The desired result output:

```
fruit_type;fruit_color;fruit_weight
Apple;Red;2
Orange;Orange;4
Watermelon;Green;15
```

What i was thinking is divide the cells into rows and then parse the values to get the correct one but i don't know how to start.

Some help will be appreciated.

EDIT 1:

```
#!/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
fileData = pd.read_csv('articles.csv',delimiter=';')
fileData.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
fileData.dropna(subset=['fruit_type','fruit_color','fruit_weight'], inplace=True)
fileData = fileData.applymap(lambda x: x.split('|'))
idx = fileData.index.repeat(fileData.fruit_weight.str.len())
fileData =  fileData.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.concatenate(x.tolist())), 0)
print fileData
fileData.assign(idx=idx).groupby('idx', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('fruit_weight', ascending=False).head(1))
```

Comment: What is this horrible CSV format?

Comment: An output from web crawling :<

Comment: Is that actually your desired output? I'd have imagined you'd want Banana;Yellow, Pineapple;Brown, Grape;Purple and Watermelon;Green etc... in there...

Comment: Web crawling? Okay, so it looks like you've taken and joined the TDs of some table instead of looping over the TRs and then taking the TDs as a group? Can you fix that maybe?

Comment: I just want to get the fruit with the higher value on weight column  on every row and ignore the others.

Comment: What, exactly, are you working with? This is a *string?*

Comment: @JonClements its the result from div autogenerated data, i can't fix it while crawling, just parse the results.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga its a csv file

Comment: I'd suggest to do this in two steps, first step being to fix the atrocious input data format into something easier to handle, then next step extract your data should be a lot easier. Not judging, just some honest advice.

Comment: What does `print fileData` and `print idx` show?

Comment: i can't do print idx because it still crashes ( even with pandas updated to the latests version ) but i've realized that there's some NaN values i'll try clear'em and try again.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Yeah that was the problem now i get the desired output, just need to store the results into csv file, Thx very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

text = '''fruit_type;fruit_color;fruit_weight
Apple|Banana;Red|Yellow;2|1
Orange;Orange;4
Pineapple|Grape|Watermelon;Brown|Purple|Green;12|1|15'''

buf = io.StringIO(text)

df = pd.read_csv(buf, sep=';')   # replace "buf" with your CSV filename
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('|'))

df

                       fruit_type             fruit_color fruit_weight
0                 [Apple, Banana]           [Red, Yellow]       [2, 1]
1                        [Orange]                [Orange]          [4]
2  [Pineapple, Grape, Watermelon]  [Brown, Purple, Green]  [12, 1, 15]
```

After loading and setup, flatten your dataframe using `apply` + `pd.Series` + `np.concatenate`. At the same time, create an index that makes grouping easy in the next step.

```
idx = df.index.repeat(df.fruit_weight.str.len())

idx
Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype='int64')

df =  df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.concatenate(x.tolist())), 0)
df

   fruit_type fruit_color fruit_weight
0       Apple         Red            2
1      Banana      Yellow            1
2      Orange      Orange            4
3   Pineapple       Brown           12
4       Grape      Purple            1
5  Watermelon       Green           15
```

Now, call `groupby` + `apply` and extract one row from each group with the highest value of weight.

```
df.assign(idx=idx).groupby('idx', group_keys=False)\
       .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('fruit_weight', ascending=False).head(1))

   fruit_type fruit_color fruit_weight  idx
0       Apple         Red            2    0
2      Orange      Orange            4    1
5  Watermelon       Green           15    2
```

Comment: I'm trying your code and i'm getting "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" on the last line ( doing an output print 1 line before looks nice ). Any idea ? ( i'll put the sample code written ).

Comment: @EliasCortAguelo It's possible that it's a pandas issue. Upgrade to the latest version - that's the one I'm on - `pip install --upgrade pandas`.

Comment: @EliasCortAguelo Before you are swayed by any dissenting opinions, my solution was not designed for speed, but more to help you understand how a problem like this can be solved by breaking it into small, manageable chunks. Step 1 - input, Step 2 - input reshape, Step 3 - retrieve results. And so on. If your question asked for the "most efficient solution" you can bet my answer would've been different. :)

Comment: @EliasCortAguelo Also to store your results, just call `df.to_csv(filename)`. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do it would be like this:

```
#!/bin/env python

# hardcoding inputs for testing
inputs = [
    "Apple|Banana;Red|Yellow;2|1",
    "Orange;Orange;4",
    "Pineapple|Grape|Watermelon;Brown|Purple|Green;12|1|15"]

# iterate over the hardcoded inputs
for input in inputs:
    # split the input string into fruit properties
    [ fruit_types, fruit_colors, fruit_weights ] = input.split(";")

    # if there is more than one fruit, split the string into a list of fruit_types
    if "|" in fruit_types:
        # assuming that there is one color and one weight for each fruit type,
        # split the other fruit properties as well
        fruit_types = fruit_types.split("|")
        fruit_colors = fruit_colors.split("|")
        fruit_weights = fruit_weights.split("|")

        # get highest value
        max_weight = max(fruit_weights)
        # get index of highest values in fruit_weights list
        i = fruit_weights.index(max_weight)

        print("{};{};{}").format(fruit_types[i], fruit_colors[i], fruit_weights[i])

    # if there is no more than one fruit
    else:
        print("{};{};{}").format(fruit_types, fruit_colors, fruit_weights)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#create dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';') 

#split all values
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('|'))
print (df)
                       fruit_type             fruit_color fruit_weight
0                 [Apple, Banana]           [Red, Yellow]       [2, 1]
1                        [Orange]                [Orange]          [4]
2  [Pineapple, Grape, Watermelon]  [Brown, Purple, Green]  [12, 1, 15]

#get position of max weight
a = pd.DataFrame(df['fruit_weight'].values.tolist()).astype(float).idxmax(1).tolist()
print (a)
[0, 0, 2]

#convert df to dictionary
b = df.to_dict('list')
print (b)
{'fruit_weight': [['2', '1'], ['4'], ['12', '1', '15']], 
'fruit_color': [['Red', 'Yellow'], ['Orange'], ['Brown', 'Purple', 'Green']], 
 'fruit_type': [['Apple', 'Banana'], ['Orange'], ['Pineapple', 'Grape', 'Watermelon']]}
```

---

```
#extract values by position
a = {k: [k1[v1] for k1,v1 in zip(v, a)] for k, v in b.items()}
print (a)
{'fruit_weight': ['2', '4', '15'], 
'fruit_color': ['Red', 'Orange', 'Green'], 
'fruit_type': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Watermelon']}

#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (df)
  fruit_color  fruit_type fruit_weight
0         Red       Apple            2
1      Orange      Orange            4
2       Green  Watermelon           15
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)


def col(df):
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('|'))
    idx = df.index.repeat(df.fruit_weight.str.len())
    df =  df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.concatenate(x.tolist())), 0)
    return df.assign(idx=idx).groupby('idx', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('fruit_weight', ascending=False).head(1))

def jez(df):
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('|'))
    a = pd.DataFrame(df['fruit_weight'].values.tolist()).astype(float).idxmax(1).tolist()
    b = df.to_dict('list')
    a = {k: [k1[v1] for k1,v1 in zip(v, a)] for k, v in b.items()}
    return pd.DataFrame(a)

print (col(df))
print (jez(df))


In [229]: %timeit (col(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.58 s per loop

In [230]: %timeit (jez(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 19.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Worked but with 1k less results, why is that?

Comment: I only compare it for more rows dataframe. So if need more efficient code better is my solution, because 80 times faster as `cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ` solution.